# Relationship between Earth's heat dispersion rate (average surface air temperature from summer to winter time) and greenhouse gases

Tags: climate-change

What is the most effective way to study global warming and the role of greenhouse gases using a methodology based on analyzing the Earth's seasonal variations (summer-winter) of the temperature of surface air?

Comment: What do you want to know about global warming and the role of greenhouse gases?

Comment: is it possible to use seasonal surface air temperature variations to assess the role of GHG in global warming?